# MAMP on Mac won't run Wordpress(5.5.3) installer

Tags: wordpress

I have been following these instructions https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP
in order to install Wordpress locally.
Got to step 4. When visiting localhost/wordpress I get white page and that's it. Installer won't run. MAMP servers are set up and I created new database like it is explained in document above. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First :
Are you sure you should visite : localhost/wordpress and not localhost:8888/wordpress, it's not a good idea to run MAMP on the default 80 port. by default it use 8888.

Then :
If not working you will have some logs from Apache and/or PHP. You can access the logs from the top menu or please search for "php_error.log" or "error.log". There you will find a message about why app is not working.

Comment: I made it work by changing port as you suggested. This is a bit confusing since tutorial suggests port 80 and according to tutorial, if I use port 80 then I don't have to use port number when accessing page through browser.